# Swift DoublyLinkedList of DataStructure

Tags: swift, data-structures

I am studying data structures with raywenderlich. Using DoublyLinkedList, I wrote a function that removes the index I want. However, when I ran the code, I deleted all the lists. I am not sure what is the problem. Any hints or references will be appreciated.

Create Node

```
public class Node<T> { 

    public var value: T 
    public var next: Node<T>?
    public var previous: Node<T>? 

    public init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Delete func

```
public func remove(_ node: Node<T>) -> T {
    let prev = node.previous
    let next = node.next 
    
    if let prev = prev {
        prev.next = next

    } else {
        head = next 
    }
    
    next?.previous = prev
    
    if next == nil {
        tail = prev 
    }
    

    node.previous = nil
    node.next = nil
    
    return node.value
}
```

Code (If push DeleteBtn , remove the node = "3+3" ,List Name is Expression

```
  @IBAction func DeleteBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let DeleteText = Delete.text!
        let  node = Node<String>(value: "3+3")
        Expression.remove(node) //<- I want to remove only "3+3"data node but this code remove all List
        print(Expression)
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I would suggest that `previous` should be `unowned` (or `weak`). Right now, every node in your linked list is creating a strong reference cycle with the preceding and following nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
let node = Node<String>(value: "3+3")
```

The problem is that this is a new `Node` instance, not in any linked list. Perhaps you had another `Node` with the same `String` value in your linked list, but that doesn’t matter. This is a new, unlinked, instance. This is unlinked instance has no `previous` or `next` values.

Then consider the attempt to remove it from your linked list (replacing `Expression` with `linkedList`, following convention that variable and property names always start with a lowercase letter):

```
linkedList.remove(node)
```

When you hit the `if let prev = ...` line, that will fail (because your new `Node` instance is not linked to anything), it will fall through to the `else` clause, and the `remove` method is setting `head` to this new `Node`’s `next`. But because this `Node` is unlinked to anything, its `next` is `nil`. So, when `head` is set to `nil`, you've lost your reference to the linked list.

---

To fix this, you should not instantiate a new `Node` instance, but rather you should find the existing instance in the linked list and remove that.

---

I might also suggest that the logic for determining whether the `head` or `tail` must be updated should be dictated by whether the node in question is the current head or tail, e.g.:

```
public func remove(_ node: Node<T>) -> T {
    let prev = node.previous
    let next = node.next
    
    if head === node { head = next }
    if tail === node { tail = prev }
    
    node.previous?.next = next
    node.next?.previous = prev

    node.previous = nil
    node.next = nil
    
    return node.value
}
```

Comment: It was a good source code for studying. ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice Rob!. I tried to solve it with the method you mentioned, and I thought about it a little more and substituted the number of indexes I wanted, and solved the problem. I'll write the code so that others can see it.

1. I wrote a function to track nodes.

   ```
    public func node(at index: Int) -> Node<T>? {
    // 1: head, current Index
    var currentNode = head
    var currentIndex = 0
    // 2:
    while currentNode != nil && currentIndex < index {
        currentNode = currentNode!.next
        currentIndex += 1
    }
    return currentNode
    }
   ```
2. I have been able to track the index using the func node and delete the desired value.

   ```
    @IBAction func DeleteBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let dInteger = Int(Delete.text!)! - 1
    let node1 = Expression.node(at: dInteger)
    let node2 = ExpressionResult.node(at: dInteger)
    Expression.remove(node1!)
    ExpressionResult.remove(node2!)
    Delete.text = ""}
   ```

Thank you Rob!